# iOS : Parse query data

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, fetch

Got a question regarding query from Parse.
I have a list of users on Parse and for every single user, information, like a Timeline, regarding their life events : when was born, what did he do in a certain year, everything displayed in a `UITableView`.
The thing is that when I press the button for synchronization with Parse, not all data is retrieved. For example, I can get the data for some of them, but for others not.
What could be the reason for this ?

```
func queryParseForEventsWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler:(success:Bool) -> Void)
{
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Event")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
        {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                // The find succeeded.
                NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) events.")

                // save parse objects to core data
                Event.MR_truncateAll()

                for object in objects
                {
                    if object.objectForKey("user") != nil
                    {
                        var userEvent = object["user"] as! PFObject
                        userEvent.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock
                            {(userObj: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                                self.saveToCoreDataEvent(object as AnyObject, userId: userObj.objectId as NSString)
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.saveToCoreDataEvent(object as AnyObject, userId: "")
                    }
                }
                completionHandler(success: true)
                return
            }
            else
            {

                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
                completionHandler(success: false)
                return
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by get data for some of them? Does it give only a certain number of data items?

Comment: Yes. Found out the problem was because there is a limit of queries , up to 1000. So I had to run the query again and got all data. The problem is now,  the content loads a little bit slower. Should I change so my `UITableView` only displays first 300 cells and load while scrolling ?

Comment: If you use Parse's PFQueryTableViewController instead of UITableViewController or UITableView, it has built in pagination and pull to refresh for getting data. Just a thought.